# Binary search to find highest true index in array of booleans

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I have an array of booleans `[true, false, false, false, true]` and I need to find the highest index (between 0 and 1000) that is `true`, I think binary search is the best way of doing that but I don't know how to adapt the algorithm to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search can be applied on an ordered(non-decreasing/non-increasing) function. 
Your array of booleans doesn't seem to have such an order.
Think about it like this, if you are at the current element say `mid`, if `arr[mid] == false`, where are you gonna jump? To the right half or to the left half? To decide where to jump you need some ordering for your boolean array.

Now coming to your question, you can have two approaches:

1. Just reverse loop from the end index and break on the first boolean value you encounter.
2. If you can store the array of booleans as a bitmask representation, then you can find the rightmost set bit in `log(n)` time.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the length of my array, it could be any size, so I think this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: btw, the order is that I know that the array is from 0 to X, so the index is the order, does it make sense?

Comment: I do not think that packing 1000 bitsi array in 64 bits chunks is worth it . Reverse loop has o(n) iterations in worst case and I believe that in average it is log(n). Probably the most optimal solution.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg An average complexity of a linear search (assuming that the arrays distribution is uniform) is constant, `O(1)`.